# expression does not have a name error - dynamic C# object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want to serialize a list of objects which could be of lots of different types which I've done in the function below. But I want to give a name to each object. I looked at using nameof but I get "expression does not have a name" when I do this - nameof(LogProperties[i]). Are there any ways to achieve this - I was thinking is there a way to add a metaproperty to the objects I want to log. I'm open to alternative suggestions.

```
    public static string CreateAdditionaLog(params object[] LogProperties)
    {
        var log = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

        for (int i = 0; i < LogProperties.Length; i++)
        {
            var prop = LogProperties[i];
            log.Add(prop.GETNAME(), prop);
        }
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the object name, you can use reflection to get the `Type` of the object

```
for (int i = 0; i < LogProperties.Length; i++)
        {
            var prop = LogProperties[i];
            log.Add(prop.GetType().Name, prop);
        }
```

Comment: It seems to give the objects anonymous type name e.g. "Dictionary`2"

Comment: Do the objects actually have names or is this a collection of anonymous objects

Comment: Good point. It's a parameter list, which I think I convert to a dictionary of Expando objects. I'm not near my computer now.